# Gamemaker: How to get an enemy to choose which object to shoot first:

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-maker

In Game Maker, there is this AI, in which I am attempting to design... This AI chooses which object to shoot first depending on the distance of the object away from it. However, this AI system does not only calculate the distance of one object, it calculates the distance of several objects. Therefore: *instance_nearest* wont work, because it may only be used to calculate the distance of a **specific object.**

*Here's the code:*

```
if object_exists(E_soldier_AI){
   if(distance_to_object(E_soldier_AI) < global.Dis){
      var t1 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI).x;
      var t2 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI).y;
      instance_create(t1 ,t2, NB);
   }
}
if object_exists(E_soldier_AI2){
   if(distance_to_object(E_soldier_AI2) < global.Dis){
      var t1 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI2).x;
      var t2 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI2).y;
      instance_create(t1 ,t2, NB3);
   }
}
if object_exists(E_soldier_AI3){
   if(distance_to_object(E_soldier_AI3) < global.Dis){
      var t1 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI3).x;
      var t2 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI3).y;
      instance_create(t1 ,t2, NB4);
   }
}
if object_exists(ETank_AI){
   if(distance_to_object(ETank_AI) < global.Dis){
      var t1 = instance_nearest(x,y,ETank_AI).x;
      var t2 = instance_nearest(x,y,ETank_AI).y;
      instance_create(t1 ,t2, NB2);
   }
}
```

This code will not also "cut it," because the code only seems to check if object E_soldier_AI exists, and the commands underneath the "if" statement, but it doesn't consider the other "if" statements afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what it i you want to do, and not familiar with GameMaker. However, from my understanding you want to parse through the distances of the available enemies and select the closest one to attack.

Try something like this (partly psuedo-code):

```
var closestDistance = 5000, closestT1, closestT2, closestEnemy;
if object_exists(E_soldier_AI){
   if(distance_to_object(E_soldier_AI) < global.Dis){
      closestDistance = distance_to_object(E_soldier_AI);
      closestT1 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI).x;
      closestT2 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI).y;
      closestEnemy = NB;
   }
}
if object_exists(E_soldier_AI2){
   if(distance_to_object(E_soldier_AI2) < closestDistance ){
      closestDistance = distance_to_object(E_soldier_AI2);
      closestT1 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI2).x;
      closestT2 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI2).y;
      closestEnemy = NB3;
   }
}
if object_exists(E_soldier_AI3){
   if(distance_to_object(E_soldier_AI3) < closestDistance ){
      closestDistance = distance_to_object(E_soldier_AI3);
      closestT1 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI3).x;
      closestT2 = instance_nearest(x,y,E_soldier_AI3).y;
      closestEnemy = NB4;
   }
}
... (Do the same for the tank)
instance_create(closestT1 ,closestT2 , closestEnemy);
```

(The next step is to put all the enemies into an array and make a loop instead)